# I have something urgent {need / needs} your help?

Tags: conjunctions, clauses, subject-verb-agreement

I want to ask for help from someone and it's quite urgent. What should I say?

> I have something urgent **need** your help?

or

> I have something urgent **needs** your help?

or even something else?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

> I have something urgent need your help?

and

> I have something urgent needs your help?

both are incorrect grammar, you should say

> I have something urgent, I need your help.

or

> I have something urgent that needs your help.

or

> I have something urgent needing your help.

Comment: You can also say "I have something urgent **needing** your help."